# RMagick ignores the opacity when creating a new image with RVG

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm trying to generate an image with a transparent background, but not even creating an image that is just a transparent png works. I tried this:

```
require "rvg/rvg"

rvg = Magick::RVG.new(100, 100)
rvg.background_fill = "pink" # Shouldn't matter
rvg.background_fill_opacity = 0
rvg.draw.write("transparent.png")
```

which generates:

[image]

I also tried:

```
rvg.background_fill.opacity = 0
rvg.styles(:fill_opacity => 0)
rvg.styles(:opacity => 0)
```

They all ended up with a solid pink rectangle.

How do I generate a transparent png using RMagick's RVG?

**Update**: the image seems to not even intend to be transparent:

```
1.9.2p320 :007 > rvg.draw
 => transparent.png  100x100 DirectClass 8-bit 
1.9.2p320 :008 > rvg.draw.alpha
 => false 
1.9.2p320 :009 > rvg.draw.alpha?
 => false
```

Comment: I know nothing about rmagick but can you use a rgba value instead of pink? rgba(250, 218, 221, 0.5)

Comment: @Bonzo, that's a good idea. I believe that's what I tried with rvg.background_fill.opacity = 0. If I inspected the color and it had the alpha value set to 0, but still didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Before rvg.image.write, add this line:

rvg.draw.alpha(Magick::ActivateAlphaChannel)

Then you don't need to set background_fill and the resulting image will be nice, smooth transparent image.